# Need help finding and printing the average of a row of a 2D array, with the use of some functions

Tags: c, arrays

So I'm trying to make a program that creates a 2d array with random numbers, then prints it, with the use of functions.

After that I need to print out the average of every row of that 2d array, so I figured I will create another array and input the average's of every row and then print that average array called `avgLine[]`.

This code does not return any errors but when I try to run it after printing the 2d array the program crashes, I need help making it work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define nmax 100

//creates a 2d array and fills it with random numbers//
void fillPin2D(int n,int p[][nmax]){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
     for(j=0;j<n;j++){
      p[i][j]=rand() % 11;
     }
    }
}

//prints out the 2d array//
void showPin2D(int n,int p[][nmax]){
    int i,j;
 for(i=0;i<n;i++){
  for(j=0;j<n;j++){
    printf("%d ",p[i][j]);

  }
 printf("\n"); }
}

//finds the average for every row and inserts it in a new array called avgLine[]//
void findMeanLine(int n,int p[][nmax]){
    int sum,i,j;
    double avg,avgLine[i];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
       sum=sum+p[i][nmax];
     for(j=0;j<n;j++){
     }
    }
    avg=sum/n;
    avgLine[i]=avg;

}

//prints out the avgLine array//
int showPinDouble1D(int n,double avgLine[]){
    int i;
 for(i=0;i<n;i++){
  printf("%lf",avgLine);
 }
}

main(){
   int n,i;
//here is a check so the program accepts integers > 5//
   do{
    printf("Give integer n > 5 : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
   }while (n<5);
    int p[n][nmax];
    fillPin2D(n,p);
    printf("p = \n");
    showPin2D(n,p);
    findMeanLine(n,p);
    double avgLine[i];
    printf("p = \n");
    showPinDouble1D(n,avgLine);
    system("Pause");

}
```

Comment: online compiler gives some errors: https://ideone.com/045jmD You should try to fix them

Comment: `double avgLine[i];` here `i` isn't initialized. Enable all compiler warnings and read them.

Comment: `avgLine[i]=avg;` this line shoud be inside the for loop. Also `sum=sum+p[i][nmax];` this is undefined behavior

Comment: Please note the assembly generated with optimizations enabled for the posted `findMeanLine` function: https://godbolt.org/z/S4qS8j . Both `avg` and `avgLine` are local variables, they won't outlive their scope.

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in the posted code, most of them detectable by the compiler, with a proper warning level (see e.g. the diagnostic [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1eZQDQyZ4wdmK9zJ)) and originated by what seems to be a misunderstanding of memory allocation and lifetime of scoped variables.

> make a program that creates a 2d array with random numbers

After retrieving the size `n`, (I'll ignore OP's method, here) the array is declared as

```
int p[n][nmax];  // Where nmax was previously defined as 100
```

Given that in the following the array is always treated as a *square* matrix, it would be better to declare that variable length array as

```
int p[n][n];
```

In that case, all the function signatures have to be changed into  something like

```
// prints out the 2d array
void showPin2D(int n, int p[][n]) { /* ... */ }
//                            ^
```

The main problem, though, is the averages are calculated. In `main` an array of *unknow* size is declared and passed to a function that prints it.

```
double avgLine[i];  // Where 'i' has an undetermined value, beeing uninitialized.
```

But it is never initialized nor modified in function `findMeanLine`, where a *local* variable with the same name is somehow used.

```
void findMeanLine(int n,int p[][nmax]) {
    int sum,i,j;              // Uninitialized variables, their values are undeterminated
    double avg, avgLine[i];   // Both are local, invisible to the outside
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
       sum=sum+p[i][nmax];    // It shouldn't be here and `nmax` is wrong
       for(j=0;j<n;j++) {     // It literally does nothing
       }  
    }
    avg = sum / n;            // Useless
    avgLine[i] = avg;         // Now 'i' is equal to `n`, so this would be an out of bounds access
}
```

It could be fixed passing the array declared (with the correct size) in `main` as an argument of the function.

```
// in main:
// ...
double avgLine[n];
findMeanLine(n, p, avgLine);
showPinDouble1D(n, avgLine);
// ...

// Finds the average for every row and inserts it in a new array called 'avgLine'
void findMeanLine(int n,int p[][n], avgLine[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
       // The average of every line, so reset the sum every time...
       int sum = 0;              
       for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
       {
           sum += p[i][j];
           //         ^^^ 
       }
       avgLine[i] = (double)sum / n; // We want a real division, not an integer one.
    }
}
```